# Mac EasyCAP with OpenCV/Python

Tags: python, macos, opencv, video-capture, v4l2

Is there a way to use my EasyCAP usb video-grabber as normal video source via OpenCV (with its own index).

For instance:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

The problem is that I can see my EasyCap connected in the USB-devices list. I can even watch a grabbed video using EasyCapViewer for Mac, but I need to do some extra stuff (e.g. face recognition and motion detection).

I am looking for some alternative of the V4l2 driver for Mac.

Comment: Not enough code for all the questions you're asking.

Comment: Serg, the mess is not about a code. Using OpenCV i can access any video source using the code above, but that source must be supported by the platform running the code. On linux, all the job is done by v4l. (stk1160 driver is the part of linux kernel). 

But Mac doesn't officially support that chipset (stk 1160). There are some programs, but i need to access video stream from my EasyCap directly, not via that software.